# How can I fix the issue of navigating to an MVC3 area causes multiple requests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6

I have an MVC3 application that has an Admin portion that is redirected via a link from the _layout of all pages that are not located within the Admin area. When the link is clicked in FF, IE, or Chrome, the page makes multiple requests and then returns a "Problem loading page" error.

I have looked at the code several times to see if there is anything that could be causing this, but everything works until the application is published to the web server. The project debugs without issues navigating to the Admin area. I feel the issue is very likely server compatibility as the server is running IIS6.

We have tried implementing the "Wildcard mapping" to the server, but this did not help.

Just to be clear, the project does function and route on the server until the "Admin" area is attempted to be navigated to. The Admin area is the only "Area" apart from the MVC3 defaults. Here is what the action looks like:

```
        public ActionResult Login()
    {
        if (Session["IsAdmin"] != null)
        {
            if ((bool)Session["IsAdmin"])
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Handbook");
            else return View();
        }
        else return View();
    }
```

And here is the actionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Login", "Admin", new { Area = "Admin" }, null })
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Login", "Admin", new { Area = "Admin" }, new {} })
```

And while you are in the Admin area, if you want to link to something outside of Admin area you can try

```
@Html.ActionLink("Handbook", "Index", new { area = "", controller = "Handbook" })
```

or within controller

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Handbook", new { area = "" });
```